# Event Emitter that transmits to a client

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have an event emitter, which has two TCP sockets bound to it, on my server.

```
class Device extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this._messages = new Socket()
    this._commands = new Socket()
  }
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to get all events on this to transmit to an equivalent event emitter on the client. That is, the server will pass this information directly to the client with the same arguments and data.

I've messed around with a few things, mostly a null publication

```
Meteor.publish(null, function () {
  const listener = Meteor.bindEnvironment(() => {
    // do something here
  })
  specialClassInstance.on('data', listener)
  this.ready()
  this.onStop(() => specialClassInstance.removeListener('data', listener))
})
```

However, I am a bit stuck here because I can't find a way to make it emit the event on the client equivalent class. The only other lead I have is `Meteor.onConnection` in the documentation.

Is this possible in meteor?